# Load float register value to C variable on Arm and Arm64

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, inline-assembly, arm64

Double precision float value is saved in d0 on both arm and arm64. How could I load it to a C double variable?

Is this correct?

```
double ret = 0.f;
#if defined(TARGET_ARCH_ARM64)
    __asm__ volatile ("fmov %0, d0" : "=r"(ret));
#elif defined(TARGET_ARCH_ARM)
    __asm__ volatile ("vmov %0, d0" : "=w"(ret));
#endif
```

I have two questions.

1. For arm64, is it OK to use "=r", or better way?
2. For armv7, "=w" means "Vector floating point registers s0 .. s31" which is single precision, is it OK to load value to double?

Comment: I don't think this is going to work reliably, because the compiler might decide to use the `d0` register for something else before your `asm` gets control,  Whatever it is that loads your magic value into that register, it needs to be in the same `asm` block.

Comment: Either way, have you tried looking at the generated asm code?  That should make it pretty clear whether this is doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested and the assembly itself is OK for transferring value from register to a variable on stack or in memory.

As Nate Eldredge says, the use of register by compiler must also be considered or the result is not what we expected.